# Set Fixed Gap on Flex Tailwind

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

This is my design with flex. You can see both the div's are having different gap in between. How Can I make it equal?
**I just want to set a fixed width for the second column however I am not able to achieve it in Tailwind.**

**Code:**

```
    <div className='bg-gray-1000 rounded shadow border border-opacity-50 text-white flex flex-col lg:flex-row w-7/12 mx-auto justify-between p-2 mb-2 items-center'>

            <div className='bg-primary rounded w-14 h-14 flex items-center'>
                <img src={props.logo}/>
            </div>

            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                <div>{props.title}</div>
                <div className='flex'>
                    <div><img className='w-6 mt-1' src={props.flag}/></div>
                    <div><FaInfoCircle className='inline ml-2 text-xl'/></div>
                    <div><button className={`ml-2 rounded px-4 py-0 text-sm uppercase bg-${props.color}-600`} disabled>{props.mode}</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                <div><FaCalendar className='inline mr-2 text-xl'/> {props.date}</div>
                <div className='mt-1'><FaClock className='inline mr-2 text-xl'/> {props.time}</div>
            </div>

            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                <div> <FaUsers className='inline mr-2 text-xl'/> {props.vs}</div>
                <div className='mt-1'><FaUsers className='inline mr-2 text-xl'/> {props.slots} Slots</div>
            </div>

            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                <div><AiFillDollarCircle color='green' className='inline mr-2 text-xl'/></div>
                <div className='mt-1'><AiFillTrophy className='inline mr-2 text-xl md:text-2xl'/> {props.prize}</div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

I would love to get some help on this, cheers.

Comment: You have a width of 14 here, and flexbox always accommodates for the full width. One option would be to use a 'fake' placeholder element, which has the remaining width required to reach 14. This will have the appearance of being empty, but occupy the space required to instruct flexbox to adjust the columns as in the top image.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I have a width of 14 to the image div, that is what I needed. I was concern about the second column which includes the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `flex-grow` class to block with title and set `space-x-{value}` [class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space#class-reference) for parent so it will add gap between child elements. [Demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/rsCvbWYCwX?layout=horizontal)

**P.S.** You have `bg-${props.color}-600` which will be [purged](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html) in a production mode

Comment: thanks for letting me know about button color, cheers.